# Show/Hide product configurable attributes depending on another attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

For a configurable product I have 3 configurable attributes (color, collar & size). I want the ablity so that the collar attribute dropdown is shown only if the color black is selected. If white is selected as the color then the colloar attribute dropdown would be hidden.

[image: Configurable Attributes]

Is this possible? I know one way around it and that is to have "not applicable" to the collar values but thats not great UX for the customer

Comment: May be you can use Javascript to show / hide your collar's element depending to the value selected of your first dropdown ?

Comment: That would be fine if it was 1 attribute and 1 product but I have 1000s of products and attributes

Comment: Hi did you got any answer?